# How to stop parent containers from resizing to fit dynamic content

Tags: html, angular, sass

I have a setup like this

```
<app-component> <!-- need this to not fit the content but be reactively sized-->
 <div> <!--display:flex-->
  <form> <!-- display: flex-->
   <div> <!-- display: block-->
    <section> <!-- display: flex-->
     <div> <!-- display:flex-->
      <app-component> width:100%-->
       <div> <!-- display: flex row-->
        <div> <!-- overflow-x: scroll, whitespace: nowrap-->
          ***inserted here are photos the user is uploading***
          ***this extends from left to right ***
        </div>
       </div>
      </app-component>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
<app-component>
```

The problem is that the first app-component is resizing to fit the images as they continue to be added. immediate div containing the images, and its containing divs all act appropriately but the containing app-component fits the invisible photos which throws off the whole page.

I can easily solve this by setting static parameters for width but this is a reactive app and will have to scale to all different screen sizes so i was wondering if someone has a good solution that keeps the css fluid and not needing to add specific px sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the container to viewport units?

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
overflow: auto;
```